# items in ng-repeat disappear after a second or so in IE 11?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This only happens in IE/Edge and works as expected in Chrome/Firefox. However, in IE, the tables items display for a second and then disappear. Here is my HTML:

```
<table md-table md-row-select ng-model="upLoaders">
                    <thead md-head md-order="query.tom" md-on-reorder="getIds">
                    <tr md-row>
                        <th md-column><span>Username</span></th>
                        <th md-column>Role</th>
                        <th md-column>Approved</th>              
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody md-body>
                    <tr md-row ng-repeat="user in filtered = (users | filterArray:uploadedUsers)">
                        <td md-cell>{{user.username}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{user.role}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{user.approved}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Angularjs version to 1.7.2 above